# How, as a complete newbie with only 1 pt can I ask for guidance

Tags: discussion

So, I saw a user comment.  I wanted to ask that user why he made that assertion (specifically "two dots is a bad practice" when making an Excel reference).  However, when I select "Comment", I'm told that I need 50 pts to comment.  Fine.

So I click the person's name to go to his profile, thinking maybe I can find a link to ask him the question directly.  Can't see where I can do that (it may be there, but I can't find it).

So I go to Help, and after looking in various nooks and crannies, I can't find anything in Help (it may be there, but I can't find it).

So I start to ask this very question, and then see that it probably should be posted on Meta.

So I go to Meta, look around, don't find the answer, and try to post the question on Meta.  However, it says I need 5 points to post on Meta.

So, as a newbie with only 1 point, how do I ask for help?!?

(And yes, I like StackOverflow, consult it regularly (including via Google and MSDN), and would like to contribute as I can.)

Comment: You visit the [help/whats-reputation] and read the guidelines about how to earn reputation (points), and then do what you need to do in order to earn 5. Then you can post on [meta] all you want. You can also search on [meta] for a post with the title "How does a new user get started here?" or something similar for some suggestions. Good luck.

Comment: You are expected to research your question first.  It is already extensively covered at SO, very unlikely that you actually need to ask for help.  Fwiw, I [wrote this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034).

Comment: See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 1):

The point requirements are there so only people that are somewhat invested and interested in this community can contribute to the content.

It also stops a lot of spam and junk answers that would happen if there are no point blocks.

You only need 5 upvotes to get to 50. Answer some questions and you will have it in no time. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: So to answer the question, is the solution "Get the 50 reputation and here's how" ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you meant @ryanyuyu

Comment: Well the OP's final question is "So, as a newbie with only 1 point, how do I ask for help?!?"  And your answer does not directly answer that.

Comment: It answers the other issues he encountered with the website.